# Find entries where a Hash field includes a given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a field in my mongo database with a hash value, example:

```
Company.find('testCompany').categories
=> {"architects"=>"architects", "landscape_designers"=>"landscape_designers"}
```

How can i do a .where select on this field? So i can find entries by single categories? Like i search my database for "landscape_designers" and get all entries who have it included in there categories hash

I found something like

```
Company.where(:'categories.landscape_designers'.gt => 0)
```

but it is not working.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If the key and value in the `categories` Hash are always the same then:

```
Company.where('categories.landscape_designers' => 'landscape_designers')
```

should do the trick. If you just want to see if there's a `landscape_designers` key in `categories` then you could use [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists):

```
Company.where(:'categories.landscape_designers'.exists => true)
Company.where('categories.landscape_designers' => { :$exists => true })
```

Note that:

> `$exists` **does** match documents that contain the field that stores the `null` value.

so `$exists` will match `:categories => { :landscape_designers => nil }`. If you want to exclude that pathological case then:

```
Company.where(:'categories.landscape_designers'.ne => nil)
Company.where('categories.landscape_designers' => { :$ne => nil })
```

In any case, I think you a design problem with your schema. Your `categories` appear to be a set rather than a Hash so you're confusing the fields logical type with its implementation. You could use an Array instead of a Hash and let MongoDB's multi-keys take care of searching the array; for example, your model would say:

```
field :categories, :type => Array
# and maybe some uniqueness validation or cleanup
```

and then you could treat the array as a scalar in your searches:

```
Company.where(:categories => 'landscape_designers')
```

Then MongoDB will unwrap the array for you.

You could also monkey patch a couple things into `Set`:

```
class Set
  def mongoize
    self.to_a
  end

  def self.demongoize(object)
    self.new(object)
  end

  def self.mongoize(object)
    if(object.is_a?(Set))
      object.mongoize
    else
      object
    end
  end

  def self.evolve(object)
    if(object.is_a?(Set))
      object.mongoize
    else
      object
    end
  end
end
```

and then use:

```
field :categories, :type => Set
```

to get automatic set behavior in Ruby-land and an Array inside MongoDB.

Comment: thank you! i did a workaround for the moment, where i put the keys of the hash into a new array field, in 'before_save' but kinda suxx - funny thing is "field :categories, :type => Array" is in the model. but the post form params put it as hash into my field (multiple checkboxes) - but thx that helps much!!

Comment: You could also override the `categories=` method to convert the funky `{:a => :a}` style Hash to a sensible array. Mongoid will call the mutator method when you `update_attributes`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your Company model

```
def method_name
   categories.where("landscape_designers > ?", 0)
end
```

Comment: you may call this method name as object of company like company then
company.method_name